# Calculate the radius of Mercury's core with density, equatorial radius

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, geophysics

I have a task where I don't know how to solve the second part.

> Some data on the planet Mercury: mean density $5400$ $kg/m^3$, equatorial radius $2440$ $km$, oblateness $0.0$, period of rotation $58.81$ days.
>
> 1. Calculate the gravitational acceleration at the equator of Mercury.
> 2. Assume that the density of Mercury's mantle is $3300$ $kg/m^3$ and that of Mercury's core is $9000$ $kg/m^3$. Calculate the radius of the Mercury core."

I calculated the first part as follows:

$$M=\rho \cdot V=\rho\cdot\frac {4}{3}\pi r^3=3.286\cdot 10^{23} kg$$

$$g=\frac {-GM}{r^2}=-3.68 \frac {m}{s^2}$$

I have no idea how to proceed with the second question, so I would appreciate help.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no further details given, I would calculate it this way:

You decompose the planet into a sphere (the core) and a hollow sphere (the mantle).

You know the average density of the result, so you can calculate, what volume ratio between the sphere and the hollow sphere you need to match that ratio.

From that, you can back-calculate to obtain the radius of the sphere.

Comment: Please no one else answer this.  This answer is a perfect response to a homework-style question.